# QuickBooks online Inventory Slippage

Tags: php, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I am trying to adjust the stock on hand on QuickBooksOnline using the API. 
I can set an initial value, which then gets reduced when sales are completed. And I can create purchase orders that increase SOH when billed.
My issue is that I need a way to adjust the stock after a stocktake is done to allow for variances (stock slippage)

I cant find anything relating to Inventory Slippage or Variances in the API documentation?

thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Item entity of type Inventory and update Quantity on Hand for your use case.
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/accounting/Item